# Whites space being read into the rear of string using getline()

Tags: c++

Look, i have been writing this guessing game for a day and a half now. I keep getting errors related to using cin and getline together, and using a lot of advice I received from Stackoverflow, I thought I fixed all the bugs. Also, I realize it's best not to use >> and getline together, but to be honest, I don't know any other way, and I am afraid I will lose points if I use features of the language that our professor hasn't specifically taught us. So please just help me out, I have been ocd-ing like a maniac.

The game works correctly, and the game repeats, (I also know that using goto is evil, but this is just a very basic guessing game. I pinky promise not to ever use it in real life)

The problem arises when the game repeats a second time. After the game prompts the user to enter Y to continue, and they do, it will goto the start of my do-while loop, as it should. Stack unwinding be damned.

Next, it will read in the user input, ignoring white space at the stare of cin. But somehow, white space hops in at the end of my word after a few runs? I am baffled by this, as I thought that my loop which tests each index using the isalpha function would prevent this?

I could really use some concrete code to fix this, I have been up all night. Suggestions are fine but I don;t fully understand them and I am not allowed to use a good chunk of this languages features. Yes, I realize that is ridiculous, but I'm not my professor.

Here is a screenshot of the logical error:
[image]

Here is my code so far: You can read some of my comments to see the different paths this beast has been down:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {





    string secretWord;
    string secretWordClean = "";
    string guessedLetters; //to be loaded with _ characters equal to length of secretWord
    string incorrectlyGuessedChars = "";
    char individualCharGuess;
    char playAgain;
    size_t countOfLetters = 0; //begine count at 0
    size_t guessesRemaining;
    int guessedUsed;


begin_game://label which we can use to bring us back to the start of the do-while loop at any time

    //do{//start of the game

    cout << "Please enter a secret word: ";

    std::cin >> std::ws;
    getline(std::cin, secretWord); 
    secretWord.erase(std::remove_if(secretWord.begin(), secretWord.end(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun(isalnum))), secretWord.end());
    //std::cout << secretWord << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){
            if (isalpha(secretWord[i])){ 
                    secretWordClean += secretWord[i];
            }
        }

    secretWord = secretWordClean; //assign all alpha secret word string back to original variable for better readability
    guessesRemaining = secretWord.length() * 2;

    //cout << "Please enter a secret word: ";
    //cin >> secretWord; 

    do{//start of the guessing portion of game

     for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){
         guessedLetters += "_"; //fills guessedLetters with blanks equal to the length of the secretWord
     }

         cout << "Please guess a letter, you have " << guessesRemaining << " guesses remaining!" << endl;
         cin >> individualCharGuess;

         for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){ //every complete iteration of this for loop = one single guess
                if(secretWord[i] == individualCharGuess){
                    guessedLetters[i] = individualCharGuess; //will replace the spaces with the correct character, if guessed
                    countOfLetters++; //if any letter is guessed correctly, this indicator will be incrimented above 0
                    continue;
                 }

                if(secretWord.find(individualCharGuess) == string::npos){
                    if(incorrectlyGuessedChars.find(individualCharGuess) == string::npos){
                    incorrectlyGuessedChars += individualCharGuess;
                    }
                }
         }

         if(secretWord.compare(guessedLetters) == 0){
             cout << "You win! The word was: " << secretWord << endl;
             guessedUsed = ((secretWord.length() * 2) - guessesRemaining) + 1 ;
             cout << "You used " << guessedUsed << " guesses." << endl; 
             cout << "Play again? Enter Y for Yes, or anything else to exit: ";
             cin >> playAgain;
             if(playAgain != 'Y'){
             break; //exit the loop if user guesses all the letters and doesn't want to play again
             }
             else {
                 incorrectlyGuessedChars = "";
                 secretWordClean = "";
                 //continue;
                 goto begin_game;
             }
         }

         guessesRemaining--; //we decriment our total guesses remaining if the user does not win the game or run out of guesses

         if(countOfLetters > 0){
             cout << "You have correctly guessed a letter!" << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed correctly so far: ";
             cout << guessedLetters << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed incorrectly so far: ";
             cout << incorrectlyGuessedChars << endl;
             countOfLetters = 0; //reset the counter to prepare for next iteration of do-while loop
         }
         else if (guessesRemaining <= 0) {
             cout << "You have run out of guesses!" << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters that you guessed correctly: ";
             cout << guessedLetters << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you guessed incorrectly: ";
             cout << incorrectlyGuessedChars << endl;
             cout << "The secret word was: " << secretWord << endl;
             cout << "Play again? Enter Y for Yes, or anything else to exit: ";
             cin >> playAgain;
             if(playAgain != 'Y'){
             break; //exit the loop if user guesses all the letters and doesn't want to play again
             }
             else {
                 secretWordClean = "";
                 incorrectlyGuessedChars = "";
                 //continue;
                 goto begin_game;
             }
         }
         else {
             cout << "You guessed wrong! Keep trying, " << guessesRemaining << " guesses to go!" << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed correctly so far: ";
             cout << guessedLetters << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed incorrectly so far: ";
             cout << incorrectlyGuessedChars << endl;
         }

     }while (secretWord.compare(guessedLetters) != 0 || guessesRemaining != 0); //use to repeat the request for a single char guess

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any plans to shorten this post and put only relevant details ?

Comment: I think you need to clear the secretWord string before beginning the game loop again. You only clear secretWordClean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize with blanks (the `_` character) the string **before** the loop starts, not at the beginning of every iteration, change your code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
    guessedLetters += "_"; //fills guessedLetters with blanks equal to the length of the secretWord
}

do{ //start of the guessing portion of game
   ... rest of the code ...
```

if you don't, at every iteration of your game the `guessedLetters` variable is going to have more `_` characters appended at the end of it, spoiling your final string comparison.

You should also clear the `guessedLetters` if you plan to play again:

```
   else {
            incorrectlyGuessedChars = "";
            secretWordClean = "";
            guessedLetters = ""; // Cleanup
            //continue;
            goto begin_game;
        }
```

as a sidenote: `gotos` are a terrible programming practice and can render the code very unreadable/unmaintainable. I suggest redesigning your application without using `gotos` in a future revision.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I did as you suggested but the same issue is still there. I have updated my OP with a screenshot. It's a logical flaw and it's been evading me for hours -____-

Comment: @AdamJ fixed, take a look at the cleanup

Comment: Thanks marco. I realize that gotos are not a good choice. I added this one after the fact, it wasn't part of my initial design. I will certianly try to factor it out, but first I need to get the program running.

Comment: Marco you are a Saint. Thanks so much for your help. I realize i'm very green to this language and have a lot to learn, and you could have easily flamed/trolled me, but you didn't. Your answer got my program running and I really appreciate it.